# datetime field not migrating django

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I have changed my model, and added a `datefield` the migration does not work. Below is what I added :

```
Birth=models.DateField(editable=False,blank=True)
```

and the error I get is :

> match= date_re.match TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Is this South migrations or django => 1.7 migrations ?

Comment: the django migration python manage.oy migrate My_App

Comment: Full traceback? The migration file itself may help too.

Comment: solved ! i modified the files generated by the makemigrations to adapt the alterations of my model and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Django documentation, first step is to make changes in your model and then run makemigrations.

For example

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

After you run this code, it will be shown as

> Migrations for 'books':   0003_auto.py:
>       - Alter field author on book

And then :
Once you have your new migration files, you should apply them to your database to make sure they work as expected:

For that, you need to run

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

It will be shown

> Operations to perform:   Synchronize unmigrated apps: sessions, admin,
>   messages, auth, staticfiles, contenttypes   Apply all migrations:
>   books Synchronizing apps without migrations:   Creating tables...
>   Installing custom SQL...   Installing indexes... Installed 0 object(s)
>   from 0 fixture(s) Running migrations:   Applying books.0003_auto... OK

That's it.

For reference: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/